# Facebook Autopost. Why I still receive download library message?

Tags: social-network

I want to use Facebook Autopost. I have downloaded the facebok-php-sdk library and I have copied it to sites/all/libraries, but in status report I still receive this message. What should i do?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the facebook.php file is found at sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php.